# websocket onclose not work in Java when client offline

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, websocket

I find websocket will closed when my client(Chrome 65.0.3325.181 windows10 x64) offline,this is I expected. But is not close in my server(JavaWeb project, Tomcat 7.0.79 & 8.5.24).
How can I close the websocket in server when the client offline?

JS code:

```
var ws;
var wsUrl = 'wss://' + location.host + '/test-websocket';

window.onload = function () {
    createWebSocket(wsUrl);
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    ws.close();
};

function createWebSocket(url) {
    ws = new WebSocket(url);
    initEventHandle();
}

function initEventHandle() {
    ws.onerror = function () {
        console.log("error");
    };
    ws.onclose = function () {
        console.log("close");
    };
    ws.onopen = function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            var message = {
                id: "ping"
            };
            sendMessage(message);
        }, 5000);
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (message) {
        console.info('Received message: ' + message.data);
    }
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    const jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
    console.log('Senging message: ' + jsonMessage);
    ws.send(jsonMessage);
}
```

Java Code:

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, final Session session) throws IOException {
    JsonObject jsonMessage = GSON.fromJson(message, JsonObject.class);
    System.out.println(jsonMessage);
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("pong");
}

@OnError
public void onError(Throwable error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(CloseReason reason) {
    System.out.println(reason.toString());
}
```

In general close, for example close webpage, I can see "CloseReason: code [1000], reason [null]" in server output.

But when client offline, the onclose will work in client, log "close" in console. But nothing will print in server output.

This is why I think websocket onclose not work in Java when client offline.

So, how can I close the websocket in server when the client offline?

Comment: Offline usually means "no network connection". What do you mean by "offline"?

Comment: Also is "no network connection“? Sorry, my English is poor... For example use netlimiter to limit chrome network speed less than 1b/s. Chrome can't send "ping" to server. Then I can see "close" in chrome console, but not in server output. @Kayaman